# CSS - should i use "main a" or make a new class?

Tags: html, css

Im a total begginer.

I'm making the css of a page. I have links in the home menu, for them I created a class.

Then I went to configure the main text links and noticed that the changes I made to the a tag also affected my menu.

I thought of 2 ways to solve the problem:

I can create a new class and put in all the links in the main text OR I can specify that I only want the "a" tags inside "main", which way is considered good practice?

```
main a{
css;
}

or

.links-main{
css;
}
```

both solutions work, i want the opinion of experienced colleagues on what is the standard way.

Comment: This is far too opinion-based. There is no right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I am using CSS I usually try and do a class for those types of things unless I am pretty much 100% certain that I won't need to maintain the `<a>` tag in the future. If you don't think you will have more than one class that applies in the `.main` then it should be alright. Common practice I have seen is just to do a new class however. As Alochi said it's very much on your own accord.

Also make sure to do `.main` and not just `main` when referring to a class.